# Array or Array<Element> in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am a Swift Beginner. I found the declaration for array in swift is as follows:

```
public struct Array<Element> : CollectionType, MutableCollectionType, _DestructorSafeContainer {}
```

however, the extension for the Array is as follows:

```
Extension Array: _Reflectable {}
```

why the identifier is different?

```
Array<Element> // what does the <Element> mean? is Array<Element> a complete identifier?
```

I am trying to understand "<>", thank you!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_generics

Answer (score 0):

When declaring an array in swift you can do `Array<Element>` where Element is the type. So for an array of strings you could do

```
var array: Array<String> = ["string", "someOtherString"]
```

However, this is not a very swifty way to create an array.  The swift way to create an array of strings would be

```
var swiftyArray: [String] = ["swiftyString", "someOtherSwiftyString"]
```

Both ways are allowed.

```
print(array[0]) // prints: string
print(swiftyArray[1]) // prints: someOtherSwiftyString
```

Comment: Actually the Swifty way is more concise and relies on type inference; `var array = ["swiftyString", "someOtherSwiftyString"]`

Comment: Agreed. However, In the context of his question, explicitly stating the type was relevant.